# FriendBuy embedded widget not working

Tags: jquery

I paid for this friendbuy service but it doesn't work with their embedded code.
The error i got is ReferenceError: _frnd is not defined

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var _frnd = {
        site: 'site-e53cff82-host',
        page: 'first_campaign',
        customer: {
            id: '12345',
            email: 'email@domain.com'
        }
    };
    (function (d, l, s) {
        var a, b = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
        a = d.createElement(s);
        a.type = 'text/javascript';
        a.async = true;
        a.src = l.protocol + '//djnf6e5yyirys.cloudfront.net/js/frndby.js';
        b.parentNode.insertBefore(a, b);
    })(document, location, 'script'); 

});
```

Comment: what does that means?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are defining `_frnd` in ready handler scope. Script is watching for global variable. Easier fix is to remove declarative `var`:

```
_frnd = {
        site: 'site-e53cff82-host',
        page: 'first_campaign',
        customer: {
            id: '12345',
            email: 'email@domain.com'
        }
    };
```

Now `_frnd` is set on global scope.